# Are there any good techniques to avoid broken program state in case of unexpected crash?

Tags: c++, robustness

I have a class `UserInterface` containing a list of `Item`s (whatever they represent). The content of these `Item`s is too expensive to keep in memory due to possibly big size, so each `Item` only stores some metadata (description, preview...) for the related data, the data itself is stored on the disk in binary files. There is another class - `FileHandler`, that is responsible for managing these files. Each `Item` has `id_` associated with the related `File`. `UserInterface` has a member reference to `FileHandler` to be able to get the list of `File`s from it and represent them as `Item`s on the screen, but `FileHandler` does not even know about the existence of `UserInterface`. When the user selects an `Item` in the UI, `UserInerface` asks `FileHandler` to find a `File` with the same `id_` (as the selected `Item` has), and then this `File` can be read from the disk for further usage of its content.

But here are some drawbacks of this design:
Let's say the user wants to delete some `Item`s. They should be deleted from both UI and disk storage:

```
UserInterface::deleteItems(/*list of id's*/)
{
    fileHandler_.deleteFiles(/*list of id's*/);

    // What if a power failure or unexpected crash happens here?

    // Delete items from UI...
}
```

If something bad happens during the execution of the following method, the next time the user runs the program they will get a broken state - the UI will contain corrupted items linked to files that have been deleted. I can still check if all files listed in the UI exist, and if some of them don't, I can mark corrupted items as invalid/broken, but I would rather prefer to avoid such situations completely.

Are there any good design patterns/techniques aiming to solve such problems?

Comment: A database with transactions is one solution. Or a transactional file system if a database is not appropriate.

Comment: You’ve invented the database.

Comment: Will SQLite be an appropriate solution for this?

Comment: So long as you use transactions.https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: If you don't have a database then with files you can also first write a new file with the new data. Then swap the current file with the new file and then delete the original  file. If at any moment the system crashes you still will have consistent data on disk (worst case you miss a small change). For the UI pointing to deleted files, do a regular rescan of what is actually on disk (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program can stop at any time when the power is lost or the operating system crashes, and there is nothing you can do to avoid that.

However, it can also stop due to a controlled operating system shutdown or when your own code crashes. You can design your software so that it can close gracefully in some of these cases, by handling the shutdown message from the operating system, catching unhandled exceptions, handling `std::terminate`, handling close signals, etc.

If you use a database such as SQLite, and use transactions to write data, it can handle many of these situations for you. However, even SQLite database can get corrupted in some cases. [For more information.](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)

Because you cannot control the situation when the operating system crashes, you also need to fix any problems during your startup sequence. You should design the program so that if cannot fix corrupted database files (or other problems), it can at least detect them. In SQLite, you can execute `PRAGMA integrity_check` to see whether the database is corrupted. If your program must be able to recover automatically, you could take backups and recover the most recent backup, or you could restore the default settings.